# laravel api route not found but exists in route list

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a patch route to `routes/api.php` but I get "route not found" even after trying `route:cache`. it's registered in `route:list` and other routes in that scope are working.

this is my code:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'v1',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1',
], function() {

    Route::group([
        'prefix' => '/users',
    ], function() {
        Route::get('/{user}', 'UsersController@show');
        Route::patch('/{user}/updateStatus', 'UsersController@updateStatus');
    });

});
```

and this is my code in controller action:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller {
    public function updateStatus(Request $request, User $user) {
         # my logic
    }
}
```

the route is registered as `/api/v1/users/{user}/updateStatus` but I get 404.

by the way, I'm using laravel 8 and php 7.3

Comment: Welcome to SO ... may be `user` is not exits and your using route model biding so it retruns 404 error

Comment: are you sending JSON raw data or form-data?

Comment: model binding is working fine, I have a show action as well and model binding works well in that case. also I'm using raw json format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think web server will automatically change url to lowercase so you must use lowercase in laravel route,so you must change "updateStatus" to "updatestatus" or "update-status"

Comment: thank you. that was the problem. I changed the url to something else and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

in this code if your $user with id you send to Api not exist , you will see 404 HTTP status code .
and remember if you want to cache your routes you need to do this after any change in your routes to apply your change .

Comment: user is defined and show route for that specific user is working well. I even tried anonymous function in route definition and dd($request) but the route is not working and I get 404

Comment: @Sina for anonymous function you must define all route parameters . did you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your route prefix it should be "api/v1"

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1',
], function() {
```

Also try

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: the routes are in the `routes/api.php` and automatically they get api as prefix. also other routes are working. I changed the order of routes as well. could it be the problem?

Comment: You can try by changing order but that should not matter.

Comment: this could be happening because you have used User $user as second param, you should use only $user. Try this it should do the trick.